# Use facet_grid and annotate in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Let's say I have the dataframe `d` (`dput` below). I would like to plot it with filled bars facetted by `Task` and `Event` and annotated with the number of values which make up each bar.

```
ggplot(inter2, aes(Aud, fill = value)) + 
    geom_bar(position = 'fill') + 
    facet_grid(Task~Event) + 
    annotate('text', label = as.character(table(inter2$Aud)), x = 1:nlevels(inter2$Aud), y = 1)
```

Problem is that I cannot figure out how to arrange the `label` vector within `annotate()`.

If I use only `facet_grid()` then I get the facetting:

```
ggplot(inter2, aes(Aud, fill = value)) + 
    geom_bar(position = 'fill') + 
    facet_grid(Task~Event)
```

[image: grid]

If I use only `annotate()` then I get the numbers:

```
ggplot(inter2, aes(Aud, fill = value)) + 
    geom_bar(position = 'fill') + 
    annotate('text', label = as.character(table(inter2$Aud)), x = 1:nlevels(inter2$Aud), y = 1)
```

[image: numbers]

But I cannot figure out how to set the `label` argument of `annotate()` to work with `facet_grid`. Any help?

```
d = structure(list(Event = c("Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", 
                     "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Lecture", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session", "Interactive session", 
                     "Interactive session", "Interactive session"), Task = c("Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", "Prepare", 
                                                                             "Prepare", "Prepare", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", "Deliver", 
                                                                             "Deliver", "Deliver"), Aud = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                      5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                      4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                      2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                      4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                      3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                      5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                      4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Funders/Donors", 
                                                                                                                                                                          "Non-scientific, lay audiences", "Policy makers", "Scientists with expertise dissimilar to mine", 
                                                                                                                                                                          "Scientists with expertise similar to mine"), class = "factor"), 
           value = c("A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "Much more confident", "A little more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "Much more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "Much more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "About the same as before", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "About the same as before", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "Much more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "Much more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "Much more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "Much more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "About the same as before", "About the same as before", 
                     "A little more confident", "About the same as before", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "About the same as before", "About the same as before", 
                     "A little more confident", "About the same as before", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "Much more confident", "Much more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "A little more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "Much more confident", "About the same as before", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "About the same as before", "Much more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "Much more confident", "About the same as before", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "A little more confident", "A little more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "About the same as before", "About the same as before", 
                     "Much more confident", "About the same as before", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "About the same as before", "About the same as before", 
                     "Much more confident", "About the same as before", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "Much more confident", 
                     "About the same as before", "Much more confident", "A little more confident", 
                     "Much more confident", "About the same as before", "A little more confident", 
                     "A little more confident", "Much more confident", "About the same as before", 
                     "Much more confident")), row.names = c(NA, -207L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Event", 
                                                                                                         "Task", "Aud", "value"))
```

Comment: annotate doesn't allow panel-specific annotations; you have to use a geom layer for that.

Comment: your code doesn't run and most R editors are going to need that `dput` output wrapped to work.

Comment: @baptiste, is there a way to use `geom_text()` in such a way that the same text is not stacked on top of itself for each row in the dataframe? @hrbrmstr, I know the first plot doesn't work, it's my problem code. Thanks for letting me know about the `dput` issue. Corrected.

Comment: Make a new data frame of annotations, one line per annotation you want. Then there will be no stacking with `geom_text`.

Comment: @Gregor, if you can expand this into an answer, that would be helpful.

Comment: No time now, if it's still unanswered tomorrow I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to pre-process the data to make a geom_text layer with the facetting variables,

```
 library(plyr)
 d2 <- ddply(d, .(Task, Event), function(.d) data.frame(table(.d$Aud, dnn=list("Aud"))))

 ggplot(d, aes(Aud, fill = value)) + 
   geom_bar(position = 'fill') + 
   facet_grid(Task~Event) +
   geom_text(data=d2, aes(Aud, y=1, label=Freq), 
             vjust=1, fontface=4, col="white", inherit.aes=FALSE) +
   theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]